# Save Azure Storage Account properties to CSV

Tags: powershell, azure-storage

I'm running following piece of code to get Storage Account TLS version from all my Storage Accounts from all my subscriptions. Only issue at the moment is that I can't export result to CSV so I could forward results. What to add to code so that it would save storage account name, resource group, subscription and TSL version to one row but in separate columns?

```
  [PsObject[]]$data = @()

#$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
#foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions) {
    #Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub.Name | Set-AzContext
    $storageaccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount
    $storageaccounts| ForEach-Object {
      Write-Host Checking $_.StorageAccountName
      $tls = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName -Name $_.StorageAccountName).MinimumTlsVersion
      # create a custom object to store the information about a storage account 
      $tlsVersionData = [PsObject]@{
        "StorageAccountName" = $_.StorageAccountName
        "ResourceGroupName" = $_.ResourceGroupName
        "TLSVersion" = $tls
      }
      # add that custom object to the array
      $data += $tlsVersionData
    }
#}

# write a CSV file containing this data
$data | Export-Csv C:\temp\data.csv
```

Write host shows right information about storage account to screen but I'm bit lost how to save data to CSV.

Comment: CSV has each row terminated by carriage return, and data seperated by columns (it's actually a terrible format - I suggest a different delimiter like `|` or `~`) so you could jusy stuff those values in there. But I'd say there is a cmdlet that does it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid adding elements to an array (which has a static length) using `+=` addition.
By doing that, you will waste time and memory because for every item you add to it, the entire array needs to be rebuilt in memory.

The fix is to let PowerShell collect the data for you like below.

As for the output to Csv, add switch `-NoTypeInformation` to the Export-Csv cmdlet so it will not write field type information at the top.

```
$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
$data = foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions) {
    # suppress output on this line
    $null = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub.Name | Set-AzContext
    Get-AzStorageAccount | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host Checking $_.StorageAccountName
        $tls = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName -Name $_.StorageAccountName).MinimumTlsVersion
        # create and output a custom object to store the information about a storage account 
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            StorageAccountName = $_.StorageAccountName
            ResourceGroupName  = $_.ResourceGroupName
            TLSVersion         = $tls
        }
    }
}

# write a CSV file containing this data
$data | Export-Csv -Path .\data.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note: `Export-Csv` by default uses the comma as field delimiter character. If you want a different character, you can specify that using the `-Delimiter` parameter.

---

In fact, you could write the above without the ForEach-Object loop like this:

```
$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
$data = foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions) {
    # suppress output on this line
    $null = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub.Name | Set-AzContext
    # let Select-Object output the objects that will be collected in variable $data
    Get-AzStorageAccount | Select-Object StorageAccountName, ResourceGroupName,
                                         @{Name = 'TLSVersion'; Expression = {$_.MinimumTlsVersion}}

}

# write a CSV file containing this data
$data | Export-Csv -Path .\data.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like below:

```
[PsObject[]]$data = @() #define an array that will hold the data

$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions) {
    Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub.Name | Set-AzContext
    $storageaccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount
    $storageaccounts| ForEach-Object {
      Write-Host Checking $_.StorageAccountName
      $tls = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName -Name $_.StorageAccountName).MinimumTlsVersion
      # create a custom object to store the information about a storage account 
      $tlsVersionData = [PsObject]@{
        "StorageAccountName" = $_.StorageAccountName
        "ResourceGroupName" = $_.ResourceGroupName
        "TLSVersion" = $tls
      }
      # add that custom object to the array
      $data += $tlsVersionData
    }
}

# write a CSV file containing this data
$data | Export-Csv .\data.csv
```

Comment: This seems to work but some odd reason the csv look weird. First row in csv is: IsReadOnly,"IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized","Keys","Values","SyncRoot","Count" and second:  False,"False","False","System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection","System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection","System.Collections.Hashtable","3". $data prints the right infomration but somethings is happening during export maybe

Comment: That’s weird. When I ran the code, I got proper data in CSV file. Please edit your question and include your exact code as well. I’ll take a look.

Comment: Now edited. I have commented out subscription loop because testing so it wont loop all subscription in test phase.  Running it from PSVersion 7.1.5. Tried also to run it from ISE in Ps version: 5.1.18362.1801 but same results.

Comment: I tried your updated code and got proper result back. My CSV file contained the appropriate information. I am running the code in Mac version of PowerShell but that should not make any difference.

Comment: Better collect the data using `$data = foreach ($sub in $Subscriptions) { ... }` and inside the loop simply output the `[PsCustomObject]@{..}`. Also, to avoid extra info is written to the Csv, add switch `-NoTypeInformation` to te Export-Csv cmdlet